# Automatically create a folder after creating the user

Tags: directory, users

Hello and do not be tired

How to create a directory for a user automatically after creating a new user?

For example, after creating a user, a directory with a username is created in the / mnt / sda1 folder.

I am using an adduser

Comment: Do you mean the user home directory?

Comment: @ahmadreza There are many methods to create user. Which you use?

Comment: If you use `adduser` to create the user, then you should be able to perform additional post-creation tasks via a `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` script

Comment: @steeldriver 

 That's right I'm using an adduser

Answer (score 3):

From `man adduser`

> If the file `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` exists, it  will  be  executed  after  the  user account  has  been  set  up  in  order  to  do  any  local setup. The arguments passed to adduser.local are: `username uid gid home-directory`.

So, you can create the file and add a simple script, e.g.:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# This script is executed at the end of adduser
# USAGE:
# adduser.local USER UID GID HOME

mkdir "/mnt/sda1/$1"
chown $2:$3 "/mnt/sda1/$1"
```

Not sure, but you might need to make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local
```